# How can I use co-routines to update my adapter in chunks(instead of all at once)?

Tags: android, r, performance, kotlin

EDIT:  I've slightly modified the question thanks to insights in the comments.

So I'm filltering and mapping one list of objects to another list of objects.  The code is here:

```
val backingData: List<AddLeadViewData> = leadList
        .filter { it.address.latitude != null || it.address.longitude != null }
        .map {
            val name = if (it.businessName != null && it.businessName != "") it.businessName
            else if (it.primaryContact != null && it.primaryContact.fullName != null && it.primaryContact.fullName != "") it.primaryContact.fullName
            else it.status.name ?: ""
            AddLeadViewData(name, it.address.singleLineAddress()
                    ?: "", false, it.status.buttonDrawable, it.id!!, it.status.name, it.address.city, it.address.state, it.address.postalCode)
        }.
```

This whole sequence is taking an average of 5 seconds which isn't good because the user is waiting for this info.  Some comments suggested I do this in chunks which is easy in Kotlin.  But how can I write a co-routine that will:

fetch data
then split the list into chunks
map the data (objA to objB) chunk by chunk
Then on the main thread update the adapter chunk by chunk?

I'm not sure where to start on the co-routine.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're mapping. What is `leadList`? How big is it? If you have a large list, it's going to take a while to map it. Also, this is more of a visual efficiency thing, but Kotlin has an `isNullOrBlank()` extension method for CharSequence (and String). You can replace `it.businessName != null && it.businessName != ""` with `!it.businessName.isNullOrBlank()`, etc.

Comment: The map function doesn't look too complex, so I guess the list is huge, instead of processing the whole list, try splitting it batches and process each on demand (i.e. when the user scroll)